# Google Spreadsheet API: duplicateSheet: No sheet with ID

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to duplicate a sheet using the `duplicateSheet` request using the `batchUpdate()` method:

```
body['requests'] = [
    {
        "duplicateSheet": {
            "newSheetName": date_today(),
            "sourceSheetId": int(sheet_number)
        }
    }
]

sheet = service.spreadsheets()
request = sheet.batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,
                            body=requestBody)
response = request.execute()
```

But I'm getting this error message:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/xxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid requests[0].duplicateSheet: No sheet with id: 3">
```

But the sheet does have this sheet. Confirmed the sheet's ID by using this JS code:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getIndex();
```

Answer (score 3):

Sheet ID which is used at `"sourceSheetId"` is [`gid`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#sheet_id). The sheet ID can be retrieved by `sheets.spreadsheets.get` for Python and `getSheetId()` for GAS. The sample scripts are as follows.

#### Sample for Python

```
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
request = sheet.get(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,
    fields="sheets(properties(sheetId,title))")
response = request.execute()
```

#### Sample for GAS

```
var res = [
  [i.getSheetId(), i.getSheetName()]
  for each (i in SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets())
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using this code (thanks to my colleague):

```
meta = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID).execute()
sheets = meta.get("sheets", {})

for sheet in sheets:
    sheet_index = sheet.get("properties", {}).get("index")
    sheet_id = sheet.get("properties", {}).get("sheetId")
    if (sheet_index == index):
        return sheet_id
```